# Get the URL that goes to 404 not found Tomcat

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7

I want to save the URL or URI that goes to 404 not found page in Tomcat. More clear, I customize my app to go to `/home.xhtml` when a page entered is not found, tomcat redirect to `home.xhml` whenever I enter a not found page, that's fine, but I still want the URL that make this happens, like if a user do : www.myapp.com/anotfoundpage, I want Tomcat redirect to `home.xhml` **and** I want to get the URL : www.myapp.com/anotfoundpage.

Is there any attribute in any Tomcat class that I can use to get that URL?

Comment: Look to the [referrer](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-document%27s-referrer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it, after some research i understood that we need to use the `request.getAttribut("javax.servlet.error.request_uri")` , this method returns the url caused the 404 error.

So all i need to do is, declar a servlet for example : NotFoundHandler, and mappe this class for a url-pattern : NotFound, then specifie it to tomcat 404 error :

```
<error-page>
<error-code>404</error-code>
<location>/NotFound</location>
```

Inside my servlet then, i just use request.getAttribut("javax.servlet.error.request_uri").

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of ways to do that, depending on the framework you are using to develop the application. Assuming you are using just plain servlets, you can use servlet filters, or a servlet to handle all invalid paths of your application, and then use the method [request.getRequestURI()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29) to find out the path entered by user.

For example, you can have something like that:

```
<web-app>
        <servlet>
             <servlet-name>MyRealServletOne</servlet-name>
             <servlet-path>foo.Servlet1</servlet-path>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
             <servlet-name>MyRealServletOne</servlet-name>
             <url-pattern>/realPath</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet>
             <servlet-name>InvalidPaths</servlet-name>
             <servlet-path>foo.InvalidServlet</servlet-path>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
             <servlet-name>InvalidPaths</servlet-name>
             <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>    
</web-app>
```

So, put your code for 404 requests in `foo.InvalidServlet` and make sure to show a 404 error to the user.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, well none of this answers actually helps me, to redirect tomcat to a custome page it's OK, but to get the url caused the 404 error that's what i need. @ Marcelo dias, i can't specify a url pattern for an invalid path, the url can be anything ! any url that is not exist in my webapp.

Comment: I'm not talking about redirect. See the "/*" in the mapping. That will make any invalid path entered by user to handled by foo.InvalidServlet. So there, you can play with the URI using request.getRequestURI().

Answer (score -1):

I use the following.  It is in my WEB-INF/web.xml file and is a child of the `<web-app>` element.

If you want to direct your 404s to a servlet or somewhere else you can do so by modifying the value in the `<location>` element.

```
<!-- Catch 404 errors -->
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

This requires no change to Tomcat config, only to your deployment descriptor (web.xml).